# How can I append an item n times to a list?

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list of items to multiply by a second list of `N` items.
How do I append to a new list so the `index[i]` of the first list is appended the corresponding `index[i]` number of times?

When I run the below code, it appends the elements but multiplies the string length, and does not append `N` times.

```
play_type = ['draw','sweep','counter','option','bootleg']
play_blend = [30,25,20,15,10]

play_master = []

for i in range(len(play_blend)):
    play_master.append(play_type[i]*play_blend[i])
```

Comment: You want to multiply a list with one item in it, not a string…!

Comment: `play_master.append([play_time[i]]*play_mix[i])`

Comment: @Arthur Not quite.

Comment: @ArthurHakobyan good suggestion. It is generating the desired count, but separating the multiples into their own indices within the `play_master` list. How can those indices be split out to separate elements?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to have one flat list of all items, you simply need a second loop. `append` will always append just one single item, whether it's an int or a list. It is also usually *"cleaner"* to use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function instead of iterating over indexes:

```py
play_type = ['draw','sweep','counter','option','bootleg']
play_blend = [30,25,20,15,10]

play_master = []

for typ, blend in zip(play_type, play_blend):
    for _ in range(blend):
        play_master.append(typ)
```

Or, as a list-comprehension:

```py
play_master = [typ for typ, blend in zip(play_type, play_blend) for _ in range(blend)]
```

You could, however, *"save"* one loop by using the [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method:

```py
for typ, blend in zip(play_type, play_blend):
    play_master.extend([typ]*blend)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
play_type = ['draw','sweep','counter','option','bootleg']
play_blend = [30,25,20,15,10]

play_master = []
idx = 0
for i in play_blend:
    for m in range(i):
        play_master.append(play_type[idx])
    idx += 1
print(play_master)
```

Output:

```
['draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw',
 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 
'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 
'draw', 'draw', 'draw', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 
'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 
'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 
'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'sweep', 'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 
'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 'counter',
 'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 
'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 'counter', 'option', 'option', 'option', 
'option', 'option', 'option', 'option', 'option', 'option', 'option', 
'option', 'option', 'option', 'option', 'option', 'bootleg', 'bootleg',
 'bootleg', 'bootleg', 'bootleg', 'bootleg', 'bootleg', 'bootleg', 
'bootleg', 'bootleg']
```

If this is not the intended output please clarify.

Comment: Very close Eli. Just looking to remove the indices and create one list of items.

Comment: @paaskanama I updated my answer. It fits your requests.

Answer (score -2):

An itertools version:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

play_master = [*chain(*map(repeat, play_type, play_blend))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoMwEEX3fkV2UcnCB0I3/ZIiJeq0BpLMEKeIX5/GB6WrOTCce2jjGX17oxDjK6AThiEwol2EcYSBxThr45UIQKA5y8jq7ckbgbiLh5yCXqWSywpA6Y748clPhMQGfYIBkS28ZX@agwU/7WpbqaZTTaXqTtVVfw07vSR//5dHNy@dpvxsK/FrX3iMFcUuB@M5/5soYvwC)